# Xampp problema com a porta

Tags: xampp

Instalei o Xampp para testar uns arquivos php e logo de cara aconteceu aquele erro de porta, por padrão ele usa a porta 80. Como nao consegui matar o processo (acesso negado) que esta nesta porta editei o arquivo httpd.conf mudando para a porta 8080, mas mesmo assim nao consigo testar os arquivos, só esta abrindo no navegador a pagina inicial "http://localhost:8080/xampp". Alguém pode ajudar?

Obs: quando clico no botao "admin" do xampp abre apenas uma página em branco.

Comment: `Acho que pode te ajudar:` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103924/xampp-port-80-is-busy-easyphp-error-in-apache-configuration-file `ou` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly `ou` http://pepfry.com/tutorials/solve-issue-port-80-in-use-by-system-xampp

Comment: O problema da porta você conseguiu resolver então? A Página em branco, é provavel que no htdocs (normalmente C:\xampp\htdocs) você tem um arquivo chamado index.php que está vazio. Você pode acessar seus outros arquivos através da url: `localhost:8080/seuarquivo.php`

Comment: Obrigada, consegui abrir o projeto assim: http://localhost:8080/Nome_do_projeto/

Comment: Ótimo :), que bom que resolveu...

Comment: Isso mesmo, valeu (Y)